# Removing Excess Blind Material

Tags: blinds

I have blinds on my new windows and the blinds are too long for the window opening. My guess is this is done to make them universal. How do you remove the excess and reattach the bottom?

Comment: Need more info.  Horizontal or vertical? Wood/fabric/aluminum?

Comment: @James: Faux Wood, vertical (Levolor brand)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If these are slatted miniblinds, each of the vertical strings goes down through the bottom rail and is held in place by a little button.  Once you pop out those buttons with a small screwdriver, the strings are free and you can remove the bottom rail.  Then you can un-thread the extra slats and re-thread the bottom rail back on, cut the strings and replace the buttons.

Comment: Err on the side of leaving them too long; better to have one or two slats resting on the bottom rail than to have the whole thing too short and have a gap at the bottom.

Comment: Save your extra slats as well. Metal/vinyl blinds can get bends crimped in them that you can't remove. Wood/vinyl blinds can become brittle from the sun's UV rays and break. Much cheaper to replace one or two slats from spares than to replace the whole unit. A replacement slat will probably not quite match color-wise at first with the others since they'd have faded, but if it's put as the top or bottom slat, it'll likely be hard to notice.

Comment: I used these instructions but Mike's instructions were general enough to warrant answer acceptance. http://www.levolor.com/support/install/files/TrimGoCordedWoodShorteningInstructions.pdf